# If statement doesn't run though conditions are met

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I don't get why only the first if statement is running

First I set the currentLevel property to what lies in the session

```
public currentLevel:any;

this.currentLevel = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('level'));
```

This if statement runs and the currentLevel.lvl is set to null

```
if (!this.currentLevel) {
this.currentLevel = {lvl: null};
}
```

This if statement doesn't run the first time the method is executed
It does however run the second time it is executed and then the entire 
method works as intended

```
if (this.currentLevel.lvl == null) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('level', JSON.stringify({lvl: '1'}));
  }
}
```

FULL CODE

```
setLevel(){
  this.currentLevel = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('level'));
  if (!this.currentLevel) {
    this.currentLevel = {lvl: null};
  }

  if (this.currentLevel.lvl == null) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('level', JSON.stringify({lvl: '1'}));
  }else if(this.currentLevel.lvl == '1'){
    sessionStorage.setItem('level', JSON.stringify({lvl: '2'}));
  }else if(this.currentLevel.lvl == '2'){
    sessionStorage.setItem('level', JSON.stringify({lvl: '3'}));
  }else if(this.currentLevel.lvl == '3'){
    sessionStorage.setItem('level', JSON.stringify({lvl: '4'}));
  }else if (this.currentLevel.lvl == '4') {
     sessionStorage.setItem('level', JSON.stringify({lvl: 'complete'}));
  }
  // console.log(this.currentLevel.lvl);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Don't use ==, always use === to perform logical and type checking.

**2)** You're not setting the value from the `currentLevel` after set the `sessionStorage`

```
setLevel(){
  this.currentLevel = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('level'));
  if (!this.currentLevel) {
    this.currentLevel = {lvl: null};
  }

  if (this.currentLevel.lvl === null) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('level', JSON.stringify({lvl: '1'}));
  }else if(this.currentLevel.lvl === '1'){
    sessionStorage.setItem('level', JSON.stringify({lvl: '2'}));
  }else if(this.currentLevel.lvl === '2'){
    sessionStorage.setItem('level', JSON.stringify({lvl: '3'}));
  }else if(this.currentLevel.lvl === '3'){
    sessionStorage.setItem('level', JSON.stringify({lvl: '4'}));
  }else if (this.currentLevel.lvl === '4') {
     sessionStorage.setItem('level', JSON.stringify({lvl: 'complete'}));
  }

  this.currentLevel = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('level'));
  //      
  //should log {lvl: null} at the first time when It ran
  //
  console.log(this.currentLevel.lvl); 
}
```